# Jenkins Build fail with stderr: error: unable to unlink old file path': Invalid argument

Tags: git, github, jenkins

When i tried to take a build, following error is ocured

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace D:\selenium\project
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://git@github.com/username/repository_name.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://git@github.com/username/repository_name.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
Setting http proxy: proxy_value
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://git@github.com/username/repository_name.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/repository_name/*
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e238e0de45ebc233b65b90493d3d2a802cef20q2 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f e238e0de45ebc233b65b90493d3d2a802cef20q2
FATAL: Could not checkout e238e0de45ebc233b65b90493d3d2a802cef20q2
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe checkout -f e238e0de45ebc233b65b90493d3d2a802cef20q2" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to unlink old 'src/Resources/chromedriver.exe': Invalid argument
HEAD is now at e238e0d... Initial Code

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1970)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$800(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2269)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout e238e0de45ebc233b65b90493d3d2a802cef20q2
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2293)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1173)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:566)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:491)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1737)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
testng-results.xml was last modified before this build started. Ignoring it.
Saving reports...
Found matching files but did not find any TestNG results.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone help this out? I configured Git repository url and credentials. Is there anything i missed out?

Answer (score 2):

Try to download a file LockHunter, check which process is using this file which prevent git updating it.

Normally this is caused by a previous build aborted by user and the process is not stopped with existing.